# get_map does not download full extent of map wanted

Tags: r, geospatial, ggmap

I have a data.frame `b` that consists of 51 geographical points.
Using the `ggmap` package I tried to show the points on a google map
first I downloaded the map from google using a bounding box:
`p<-ggmap(get_map(location = c(left = min(b$coords.x1), bottom = min(b$coords.x2), right =max(b$coords.x1) , top = max(b$coords.x2))))`
 but when I ploted the map :
`p+geom_point(aes(x=coords.x1, y=coords.x2),data=b, alpa=0.5, size=3)`

 I got the next  warning:
`Removed 21 rows containing missing values (geom_point)`

here is my data frame:

> `>`b
>      coords.x1 coords.x2
>   1   12.51787  41.87951
>   2   12.47803  41.89199
>   3   12.48278  41.90599
>   4   12.47687  41.89861
>   5   12.49223  41.89021
>   6   12.47090  41.90332
>   7   12.46656  41.89767
>   8   12.48494  41.90068
>   9   12.45351  41.90665
>   10  12.47221  41.89556
>   11  12.48449  41.89064
>   12  12.50552  41.89576
>   13  12.47714  41.85862
>   14  12.49313  41.87940
>   15  12.45394  41.90217
>   16  12.45446  41.90305
>   17  12.45446  41.90305
>   18  12.49214  41.91421
>   19  12.48331  41.90093
>   20  12.49060  41.88977
>   21  12.48533  41.89242
>   22  12.48111  41.89503
>   23  12.48313  41.89385
>   24  12.47454  41.89958
>   25  12.47631  41.91145
>   26  12.48694  41.88833
>   27  12.47477  41.88356
>   28  12.50742  41.88401
>   29  12.46809  41.88218
>   30  12.52118  41.91346
>   31  12.49211  41.88647
>   32  12.51339  41.88052
>   33  12.51339  41.88052
>   34  12.49666  41.88929
>   35  12.47537  41.89831
>   36  12.47733  41.89943
>   37  12.48074  41.90128
>   38  12.47543  41.90618
>   39  12.47597  41.90692
>   40  12.47724  41.90568
>   41  12.46651  41.90308
>   42  12.46693  41.92834
>   43  12.47402  41.93220
>   44  12.53848  41.83618
>   45  12.47951  41.89143
>   46  12.47307  41.89916
>   47  12.47705  41.90555
>   48  12.47938  41.90352
>   49  12.47922  41.90470
>   50  12.47639  41.91081
>   51  12.49242  41.89481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually follow the strategy of give my data a 'window' with *f* from `make_bbox`:

```
bbox <- ggmap::make_bbox(Long, Lat, data, f = 0.5)
map_loc <- get_map(location = bbox, source = 'google', maptype = 'terrain')
map <- ggmap(map_loc, extent = 'device', maprange=FALSE, darken = c(0.5, "white"))
```

Another option is to set a different **zoom** factor:

```
map_loc <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(data$lon), mean(data$lat)),
                   source = 'google', zoom = 14)
map <- ggmap(map_loc, extent = 'device')
```

play with zoom level to get the desired window area

Comment: Just adding something I learned:  once you get the window large enough to include all your points (in this case by using `f =0.54` or `zoom=12` for the 1st and 2nd solutions, respectively), there may be more extra space than you want.  You can sort of crop the plot using `xlim` and `ylim`.  For example, one could use: `map<-ggmap(map_loc, extent='device') + xlim(12.44,12.55) + ylim(41.83,41.94)`.  Also, if your window is too small (e.g. say you used `zoom=14`), you can use the same concept to zoom out, then call `geom_plot` to see where the missing points are in relation to the map.